# Using variables across django templates 2

Tags: python, django, django-models, backend

I have a program that i upload a word document and the document is converted into an html page. I'm using docx2txt to get the images and text from the document. This saves the images to a tempImages folder. I'm trying to then go through this folder and save the images to a django database. Everything else is working fine but django is not saving the images in the correct folder. please help[image: settings][image: models][image: views]

Comment: Where's it saving them?- not the `media` folder I presume? ..also don't post pictures of code, just do raw text in code blocks with markdown- it really helps with debugging and the eyes

Comment: my bad on the pictures. its not saving them anywhere or anywhere that i can find. if they are being saved i dont know what name their being saved under which makes it difficult to search for them. i think my media directory settings are correct because the documents are being saved in the right place its just the images that arent. do you know if when saving a file with django you just have to save the path to the file or is it  some sort of object? thanks for your help im a new programmer and im really struggling

Comment: The settings look fine, but I've never worked with images :| ..You should try: `Documents.filter(image__isnull=False).first().image.url` in the shell ..that **should** provide you with a path to the image- if it crashes (no found items) we know something is wrong with the saving (worth a shot)

Comment: figured it out thanks for your help